# How to deal with Tensorflow bug "Check failed: s.ok() could not find cudnnCreate in cudnn DSO"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I have written a project with Tensorflow. It went well with LSTM model, But get bug ,saying

> "Check failed: s.ok() could not find cudnnCreate in cudnn DSO" , with
>   CNN model.

Is there any one can point out the mistake of my code? 
If you want to run the code, just clone the repo: https://github.com/zhaoyu611/basketball_trajectory_prediction.
It ran well with LSTM model, in I set 'model.LSTM_model()' in line 57 in main.py. But it get an error if I set 'model.CNN_model()'.
Thx in advance.

Comment: This looks like it might be a cudnn install issue. You may find some help in the comments to this GitHub bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/722

Comment: Thx. I ran my code on another computer, it works well.